# Area51 missing link on blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, blog

The "Stackexchange" site list on the right-hand side of the blog is missing its link for "Area 51"

Comment: Pretty sure they're trying to work the bugs out before they really publicize it...

Comment: In that case it seems like bad design, cos its in a list with all the other links and I want to click it

Comment: They should put a note next to it in red, "Don't click this link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area 51 has not been announced outside of meta so the link was excluded from other references. It's probably the worst kept secret in history, but the appearance of the icon is supposed to be a bit of a teaser. Honestly, nobody has asked me about it apart from the meta-folken.

Area 51 will be announced to the public very, very soon (and linked from the blog).

Comment: why put it there is you can't click it?  "a bit of a teaser" is just frustrating...